# How to fix Magento 2 compile issue?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

How to fix compile error

```
[master_qmajkwnjbz]:public_html$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 60.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  I        nterface 'Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface' not found in /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_h        tml/app/code/Magezon/PageBuilder/Model/InstagramCacheManager.php on line 7
    
    Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface' not found in /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravq        hssbb/public_html/app/code/Magezon/PageBuilder/Model/InstagramCacheManager.php on line 7
```

---

I got this error https://prnt.sc/udsmpm

```
[ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Authorization does not exist

  [ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Authorization does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont directly run the `setup:di:compile`.

Try below commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Its still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

How i got

```
[master_vkhvxsgmux]:public_html$ bin/magento setup:di:compile
 
Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 30 secs 250.0 MiB
 
  [ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Authorization does not exist
 
 
  [ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Authorization does not exist
 
setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Magezon_PageBuilder module

(/app/code/Magezon/PageBuilder/Model/InstagramCacheManager.php )

required Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface which is not present or not properly initialized in the system

Disable/delete mentioned modules or fix this dependency